# ArrayList<HashMap> always return last value

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am fetching data from json and storing in ArrayList in Asynctask (doinbackground) - kept a log after adding to ArrayList and this displays all the items correctly.

In onPostExecute, I am printing few ArrayList at various positions - but it always prints the last entry.

Below code snippet for complete AsyncTask

```
       public class GetTheCarList extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog=ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(),"","Loading..");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br=null;

        try {
            br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getActivity().getAssets().open("vehicles.json")));
            String temp;
            while((temp=br.readLine())!=null)
            {
                sb.append(temp);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        JSONArray jsonAr = null;
        try {
            jsonAr = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mapping=new HashMap<>();
        carList=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<=jsonAr.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject jsonOb= null;
            try {
                jsonOb = jsonAr.getJSONObject(i);
                String year=jsonOb.getString("year");
                String make=jsonOb.getString("make");
                String model=jsonOb.getString("model");
                String mileage=jsonOb.getString("mileage");
                String icon=jsonOb.getString("image_url");


                mapping.put("year",year);
                mapping.put("make",make);
                mapping.put("model",model);
                mapping.put("mileage",mileage);
                mapping.put("image_url",icon);

                carList.add(mapping);
                Log.e("***", "carlist " + " " + carList.get(i)); // WORKS CORRECTLY

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        efficientAdapter=new EfficientAdapter();
            Log.e("***", "carlist " + " " + carList.get(17620)); // DISPLAYS LAST VALUE

        lvCarList.setAdapter(efficientAdapter);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: In the above mentioned link - there are two solutions given : 1) Static fields in your list object 2)Accidentally adding the same object to the list. I didnt mention the static Array list and when I log as I input, it is printing as expected

Comment: It's the second one. You're adding the same object to the list repeatedly, but each time you log it, it's been updated to the most recent value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only created one HashMap, then added it `(jsonAr.length())` many times to your carList. You just added a "reference" to the same object multiple times. You need to create a new object if you want it to be different. All those references will "update" as the data in that object changes.

To be very clear, each loop is simply changing the values in `mapping` and adding another reference to it to `carList`

move

```
mapping=new HashMap<>();
```

inside your for() loop, then see what happens.

Comment: Added the complete Async task that I am doing -

Comment: Unless something really bizzare is going on, my answer still stands. You are passing an object by reference, and expecting it to go by value.

Comment: moving mapping inside the loop - is working. Thank you